# Ternary operator within Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails, so forgive me if it's something simple, but it does seem as if though what I've written is correct. I'm using a ternary operator in my view to decide whether to add a class of active or not:

```
<li class="<% is_current_page('') ? 'active' : '' %>">
```

And I've debugged and know for sure that `is_current_page('')` is returning `true`.

Comment: It happens, relax lol.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You missed `=`

```
<li class="<%= is_current_page('') ? 'active' : '' %>">
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted to do

```
<li class="<%= is_current_page('') ? 'active' : '' %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need to do : `<li class="<%= is_current_page('') ? 'active' : '' %>">`