# How to get the data in the format of user entered not in the database stored format

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a text box for date of birth and allow users to select their date. For date select I use date_picker. While selecting, the date is in dd/mm/yyyy(08.Aug.1999) format. And after saving date into database. It displayed in yyyy/mm/dd format (1997.08.07). Because in database it stored in (1999.8.07)format. But I want it to be displayed in the same format as the user entered. How to do it?

html

```
 <input class='dob' name='user[dob]' type="text" value='<%= user.dob %>'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [**strftime**](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Time/strftime).

**Code:**

```
<input class='dob' name='user[dob]' type="text" value='<%= user.dob.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>'/>
```

Comment: Its work only for the edit. But for new It will show me error Undefined method  strftime for nil class

Comment: [Use ternary Operator to handle that case!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999757/ternary-operator-within-rails-view)